# Ionic 3 - How to implement viewpager?

Tags: android, ios, css, typescript, ionic3

I am currently developing an application using Ionic 3, the main screen consists of 3 tabs (`ion-tabs`) I created a function to change tabs according to the user's swipe, however my client asks for a transition equal to WhatsApp and I do not know to implement this. I thought of using `ion-slides` but I would have to migrate the code from the 3 tabs to a single view, is there a way to append the animation without having to change the component?

```
<ion-tabs #Tabs no-border tabsPlacement="top" tabsHighlight='true' color="secondary" >
    <ion-tab [root]="disponiveisRoot" tabTitle="Disponiveis" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="meusPedidosRoot" tabTitle="Meus pedidos" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="finalizadosRoot" tabTitle="Finalizados" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ionic2-super-tabs](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs). This library makes it possible to make swipable tabs easily. You have to check the github page for compatability and which version you should use.

With the library a basic example would be as below. It's almost the same as the tabs from Ionic it self.

> Basic example
>
> Component:
>
> ```
> export class MyPage {
>
>   page1: any = Page1Page;
>   page2: any = Page2Page;
>   page3: any = Page3Page;
>
> }
> ```
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <super-tabs>
>   <super-tab [root]="page1" title="First page"></super-tab>
>   <super-tab [root]="page2" title="Second page"></super-tab>
>   <super-tab [root]="page3" title="Third page"></super-tab>
> </super-tabs>
> ```